# Convert Java stream to regular for loop expression in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse

I use Eclipse Oxygen. Offten I need to convert Java stream to regular `for` loop and backward.

This is Java 8 stream expression:

```
taskDao.getChildTask(foundTask).stream().forEach(t-> {
    setResult(t, null);
});
```

Can I use some key or shortcut in Eclipse IDE to convert automatically this
expression to regular `for` loop:

```
for (Task t : taskDao.getChildTask(foundTask)) {
    setResult(t, null);
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: No there aren't such shortcut

Comment: IntelliJ has a short-cut

Comment: I'm not sure about eclipse has but intellij has such a facility .

Comment: Maybe clicking on the forEach string and pressing CTRL+1 helps but I am not sure

Comment: Those to examples that you have given aren't the same, the `forEach` loops unordered, while you for loop loops ordered, that might give different results in the final run.

Comment: The `stream()` isn't necessary (and might interfere with code analysis). You can call `forEach()` directly on any `Iterable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, the feature request has **not yet** been **implemented**: see **[Eclipse bug 431967](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=431967)**